# Duplicating Slides Using Python-pptx

Tags: python, python-pptx

I have a powerpoint table template with 9 rows on slide 1, while the data I want to populate on the table is about 30 rows, I tried to duplicate the slide in slide 1 to accommodate for the remaining rows in the data but my code is not working. I keep getting list index out of range error. Please help

I have tried this code

```
def add_table_slide(prs, index:int) -> None:
    source = prs.slides[index]
    duplicated_slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[BLANK_SLIDE_LAYOUT_INDEX])
    for shape in source.shapes:
        new_el = copy.deepcopy(shape.element)
        duplicated_slide.shapes._spTree.insert_element_before(new_el, 'p:extLst')

def construct_pptx(template_dir: str, content: List[SheetData], output_dir: str) -> None:
    def parse_data(sheet_data:Sheet Data, table_row_index: int, data_row_index:int) ->None:
        data1, data2,data3, data4, data5, data6, data7 = sheet_data

format_text(table.cell(table_row_index, 0), data1[data_row_index])
format_text(table.cell(table_row_index, 1), data2[data_row_index])
format_text(table.cell(table_row_index, 2), data3[data_row_index])
format_text(table.cell(table_row_index, 3), data4[data_row_index])
format_text(table.cell(table_row_index, 4), data5[data_row_index])
format_text(table.cell(table_row_index, 5), data6[data_row_index])
format_text(table.cell(table_row_index, 6), data7[data_row_index])

    prs = Presentation(template_dir)

    num_sheets = len(content)
    slide_index = 0
    MAX_ROWS = 10

    for i in range(num_sheets):
        slide_data = content[i]
        remaining_rows = len(slide_data[0])
        start_row = 0

        while remaining_rows > 0:
            slide = prs.slides[slide_index]

            for shape in slide.shapes:
                if shape.shape_type == MSO_SHAPE_TYPE.TABLE:
                    table = shape.table

                    for row in range(start_row, min(start_row + MAX_ROWS, len(slide_data[0]))):
                        data_row_index = row
                        table_row_index = OFFSET_ROW_INDEX + row - start_row
                        parse_data(slide_data, table_row_index, data_row_index)
                        remaining_rows -= 1

            if remaining_rows > 0:
                new_slide = add_table_slide(prs, slide)
                slide_index += 1
                start_row += MAX_ROWS

            slide_index += 1

    prs.save(output_dir)
```

I am getting list index out of range error on

```
`parse_data(slide_data, table_row_index, data_row_index)
```

Also in

```
 `format_text(table.cell(table_row_index,0), data1[data_row_index]`
```

Comment: Index Error, okey, but where? can you add the traceback?